# Non-Deterministic behaviour of svm{e1071}

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I noticed that SVM when fed with decision.values=T  (plus sigmoid to get probabilities ) produces non-deterministic result when I permute data frame under analysis. Does anyone has any idea why? Please try the code yourself

```
install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071)
A <- cbind(rnorm(20,1,1),rnorm(20,1,1),rep(1,20))
B <- cbind(rnorm(20,9,1),rnorm(20,9,1),rep(0,20))

dataframe <- as.data.frame(rbind(A,B))

predc <- rep(0,length(dataframe[,1]))
K <- length(dataframe[1,])
permutator <- sample(nrow(dataframe))

dataframe$V3 <- factor(dataframe$V3)
dataframe <- dataframe[permutator, ]
for(i in 1:length(dataframe[,1])) {    

  frm <- as.formula(object=paste("V",as.character(K), " ~ .",sep=""))
  r <- svm(formula=frm, data=(dataframe[-i,]))
  predicted <- predict(r,newdata=dataframe[i,],decision.values=TRUE)
  predc[i] <- sigmoid(attr(predicted,'decision.values')[1])
}


plot(sort(predc))
```

[edited: code]

Comment: What is x?  Aren't you removing a value from the training data (i.e. dataframe[-i,]) ? I don't see where you are permuting the data frame

Comment: @AndrewCassidy - yes I am removing a value from a training data (it is leave one out cross validation), permutation is realized with dataframe <- dataframe[permutator, ]

Comment: I still can't run this.  I don't know what x is: Error: object 'x' not found

Comment: Also what package is your svm from.  You need to be more specific here.

Comment: sorry, I fixed that - try now